# Element input not allowed in xhtml body

Tags: xhtml

Element input not allowed in xhtml body

this is a bit of the code after placing javascript into it, this error appeared.

```
    <p class="submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
    <button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p>
    </body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is an input tag not allowed directly within a form tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439078/why-is-an-input-tag-not-allowed-directly-within-a-form-tag)

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to make a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide your entire HTML, so I cannot say for the entire document.  Based on what you have provided, here are the issues:

```
<p class="submit" />  <---- YOU ARE CLOSING THE PARAGRAPH TAG
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
<button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p> <---- YOU THEN CLOSING THE PARAGRAPH TAG AGAIN
</body>
```

Make the following changes:

```
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
<button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button>
</p>
</body>
```

You can also validate your code here: http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose input tag inside a div or fieldset, also you have closed p tag incorrectly. Check this links [Why is an input tag not allowed directly within a form tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439078/why-is-an-input-tag-not-allowed-directly-within-a-form-tag), I hope it will be clear to you.