# What is the advantage of using Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just come across a good write up for a new ASP.NET Core feature called [Tag helpers](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6).

From there, I understood that one can replace the following code:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => p.Name, "Name:")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => p.Name)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

with:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Product
@addtaghelper "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"

<form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="Name" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

There's some new syntax such as `asp-controller`, `asp-for`, etc.  But what does it do? And what's the advantage of this new approach?

Comment: you asked your q perfectly im wondering the same thing... even from what has been provideed as answers yeah i get some of it but still only feels like 52(tag)/48 better

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The most important improvement I've seen so far is the control it guarantees over your HTML elements. While convenient, the Html helpers used by MVC create problems when you try to do things they weren't built for.

A simple example can be seen when using the TextBox in MVC5:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => p.Name)
```

The resulting HTML markup looks like:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
```

Nice and simple. But what if you want to add a placeholder attribute? What if you want to use bootstrap's validation states? What if you have some 3rd party super cool javascript library which needs custom attributes. None of these things were possible in the **initial release** of **MVC5.** Though they were eventually added via update in the form of **htmlAttributes**. Even now adding custom attributes is kludgey at best.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => p.Name, 
    new {@class="form-control has-error", placeholder="Enter Name", 
    superCoolFeature="Do something cool"})
```

While you could argue this is still less code that straight HTML, it is no longer a significant advantage. Worse, this solution still doesn't cover dashes in attributes which are fairly common. If you need them you are stuck with a workaround such as [ActionLink htmlAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108943/actionlink-htmlattributes)

I've gone down the route of fixing these deficiencies with custom editors, and tried building my own TextBox controls. It became obvious pretty quickly that replacing the included TextBox templates would require a lot of work. Worse, your templates have to have knowledge of any extensions you are adding to use them.

It seems like the inclusion of Bootstrap and other 3rd party tools into MVC have made it more obvious that the current design has problems with extending HTML which need to be fixed. Hopefully the tag helpers implementation is complete enough that we can avoid them in the future.

Answer (score 13):

Not to mention, your *Web **Designers*** will have real HTML tags to edit that they recognize to re-design your pages.  Designers shouldn't have to be coders and there's enough for these sharp folks to keep up with, studying the moving targets of HTML5 and CSS3 specs.

Answer (score 10):

A few things come to mind:

1. As @ChrisWalter points out, these tag helpers give HTML tags an Open/Closed quality. Rather than just letting you write extension methods for common HTML patterns, you can *extend* an HTML element. This lets you pick-and-mix multiple extensions per component, rather than having to choose between them.
2. HTML Helpers tend to not work super well for elements that need to have inner HTML provided as an argument. They came up with a clever pattern so you can say:

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm(...)){
   {
       <input ... />
   }
   ```

   But there's nothing about `BeginForm()` that would force you to put it in a `using` statement, and there's nothing to prevent you from using incorrect HTML structure. (`<input>` technically [isn't allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439078/why-is-an-input-tag-not-allowed-directly-within-a-form-tag) to be directly inside a `<form>` tag.)
3. This gives us a really easy transitional stepping stone into the Web Components world of HTML5. A component that you write today for jQuery or Bootstrap to pick up and enhance may make more sense as an Angular 2 or Polymer component in a few years. Using HTML syntax makes it possible to write your HTML the way you want it to look when it's a web component, and have it automatically translated into the structure it has to take on for now (or for specific browsers, later).

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is correct but just a correction.
Html Helpers cover dashes in attributes by use of underscore. for example if you want html like
my-attr=value
then you can use html helpers like
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.id,
new { my_attr = value })
then it will convert accordingly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29874609)

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question asks about *advantages* but for the sake of completeness I have to mention one *disadvantage*:

With tag-helpers enabled you cannot inject C# code inside tag attributes.

I.e. this code will break:

```
<!-- this won't work -->
<input class="@GetMyClass()">

<!-- this won't work too -->
<input type="checkbox" @(condition ? "checked" : "") >
```

To work around this problem you can use custom tag helpers or just disable tag helpers altogether like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65281018/56621

<sup>P.S. My humble opinion that can be safely ignored: tag helpers are "magic". And "magic" is always bad in programming. If something looks like an HTML tag, walks like a tag and quacks like a tag - then it should probably be an HTML tag. Without me knowning "oh, it's not *really* a tag".</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From building a basic web app from the ground up in .NET 7/Razor pages, I haven't encountered a single instance where a tag helper has an advantage over simply coding the HTML.   I don't come from an MVC background so maybe that is where the advantage lies but as seen before...Microsoft has released yet another version of wheel-reinvention that instead of making things easier for some simply adds more confusion to others.