# Assigning selected items to drop-down list on update "multiple"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, razorengine

I have an HTML.dropdown **multiple select2** working perfect. When I save values,

**BUT:** On update page I have to show the pre selected values in the dropdown

here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3" id="categorylist">
   <p class="mb-1 font-weight-bold text-muted mt-3 mt-md-0">Category*</p>
   @Html.DropDownList("pCategory[]", new SelectList(new admin.Models.CategoryModel().getMultipleCategoryBySP(), "cat_id", "cat_name", --placeToProvideSingleIntValue--), 
     new { @class = " form-control select2-multiple ", @data_toggle = "select2", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width: 100%;" })
</div>
```

in above code, there is a place holder **--placeToProvideSingleIntValue--** where I can place single integer value it shows as preSelected.

**Solution/HELP Required for:** i want to pass an array to it or multiple values anyother way. so it would show multiple pre selected values.

Comment: Have you tried the [MultiSelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) ? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737985/asp-net-mvc-multiselectlist-with-selected-values-not-selecting-properly) could also help.

Comment: @the_lotus I can't thank you enough man. That solved my problem.
Thanks a BILLION :) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a [MultiSelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instead of a SelectList. Something like

```
@Html.DropDownList("pCategory[]", new MultiSelectList(new admin.Models.CategoryModel().getMultipleCategoryBySP(), "cat_id", "cat_name", --placeToProvideMultipleIntValue--), 
     new { @class = " form-control select2-multiple ", @data_toggle = "select2", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width: 100%;" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Razor-pages(near the Blazor thingy :D) is one of the newest and most modern frameworks from Microsoft for now, so I think you should try to use tag helpers wherever is possible as you can get [so many benefits from using it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422843/9918730) 
You can have a look at the sample [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper)

So the tag component on your .cshtml page should look quite simple, like:

```
<select asp-for="pCategory" asp-items="items" multiple class="form-control select2-multiple" style="width: 100%;" data_toggle = "select2"></select>
```

where an item is a `MultiSelectList` object

```
MultiSelectList items = new MultiSelectList(Categories, "cat_id", "cat_name", 
selectedValues);
```

and `selectedValues` array of ints.
Hope it will help :)

And just one small thing out of the scope. I don't think it is nice to do something like this

```
new admin.Models.CategoryModel().getMultipleCategoryBySP()
```

on your client-side. I believe that the right thing that should be done is to pass just a flat object to the client-side and keep the whole business logic/conversions/mapping stuff in the back-end.

Cheers